# Getting Run-Time error '1004' Is my formula perhaps too long or can I fix the coding?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

So I wrote up an Array formula which works fine on my excel, but when converting it to VBA I'm getting an error: Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class. I'm not sure why I'm getting this issue. Please see the code here:

```
Selection.FormulaArray = _
    "=IF(IF(AND(OR(RC[-14]<>R[-1]C[-14],RC[-15]<>R[-1]C[-15]),Pay_Periods!R2C10<>0),MAX(IF(Pay_Periods!R2C3:R250C3>=Pay_Periods!R1C10+(14*Pay_Periods!R3C10),IF(Pay_Periods!R2C2:R250C2<=Pay_Periods!R1C10+(14*Pay_Periods!R3C10),Pay_Periods!R2C3:R250C3))),MAX(IF((Pay_Periods!R2C3:R250C3>=Sheet1!RC[-10])*(IF(AND(Sheet1!RC[-14]=Sheet1!R[-1]C[-14],Sheet1!R[-1]C[-10]<Sheet1!RC[" & _
    "-10]+14),Pay_Periods!R2C3:R250C3<(RC[-10]+14),IF(AND(RC[-14]=R[-1]C[-14],RC[-15]=R[-1]C[-15]),Pay_Periods!R2C3:R250C3<R[-1]C[-10],1))),Pay_Periods!R2C3:R250C3,"""")))=0,"""",IF(AND(OR(RC[-14]<>R[-1]C[-14],RC[-15]<>R[-1]C[-15]),Pay_Periods!R2C10<>0),MAX(IF(Pay_Periods!R2C3:R250C3>=Pay_Periods!R1C10+(14*Pay_Periods!R3C10),IF(Pay_Periods!R2C2:R250C2<=Pay_Periods!R1C10+" & _
    "(14*Pay_Periods!R3C10),Pay_Periods!R2C3:R250C3))),MAX(IF((Pay_Periods!R2C3:R250C3>=Sheet1!RC[-10])*(IF(AND(Sheet1!RC[-14]=Sheet1!R[-1]C[-14],Sheet1!RC[-15]=Sheet1!R[-1]C[-15],Sheet1!R[-1]C[-10]<Sheet1!RC[-10]+14),Pay_Periods!R2C3:R250C3<(RC[-10]+14),IF(AND(RC[-14]=R[-1]C[-14],RC[-15]=R[-1]C[-15]),Pay_Periods!R2C3:R250C3<R[-1]C[-10],1))),Pay_Periods!R2C3:R250C3,"""")" & _
    ")))" & _
    ""
```

By the way I copied it exactly how the macro itself recorded it so you may notice some spaces. I'm thinking it could just be too long, but it seems weird that writing it in the cell gets it fine, but not in the vba form. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated! I'm attempting to have this formula self insert by code and copy paste values so the excel doesn't have to keep loading in information.

Here is how the formula looks normally:

```
=IF(IF(AND(OR(C2<>C1,B2<>B1),Pay_Periods!$J$2<>0),MAX(IF(Pay_Periods!$C$2:$C$250>=Pay_Periods!$J$1+(14*Pay_Periods!$J$3),IF(Pay_Periods!$B$2:$B$250<=Pay_Periods!$J$1+(14*Pay_Periods!$J$3),Pay_Periods!$C$2:$C$250))),MAX(IF((Pay_Periods!$C$2:$C$250>=Sheet1!G2)*(IF(AND(Sheet1!C2=Sheet1!C1,Sheet1!G1<Sheet1!G2+14),Pay_Periods!$C$2:$C$250<(G2+14),IF(AND(C2=C1,B2=B1),Pay_Periods!$C$2:$C$250<G1,1))),Pay_Periods!$C$2:$C$250,"")))=0,"",IF(AND(OR(C2<>C1,B2<>B1),Pay_Periods!$J$2<>0),MAX(IF(Pay_Periods!$C$2:$C$250>=Pay_Periods!$J$1+(14*Pay_Periods!$J$3),IF(Pay_Periods!$B$2:$B$250<=Pay_Periods!$J$1+(14*Pay_Periods!$J$3),Pay_Periods!$C$2:$C$250))),MAX(IF((Pay_Periods!$C$2:$C$250>=Sheet1!G2)*(IF(AND(Sheet1!C2=Sheet1!C1,Sheet1!B2=Sheet1!B1,Sheet1!G1<Sheet1!G2+14),Pay_Periods!$C$2:$C$250<(G2+14),IF(AND(C2=C1,B2=B1),Pay_Periods!$C$2:$C$250<G1,1))),Pay_Periods!$C$2:$C$250,""))))
```

Then ctrl+shift+enter naturally

Comment: this is a fun relic of excel where the FormulaArray property setter will only take a string of 255 characters or less - even though the property itself can hold much more than 255 characters

Comment: take a look at this workaround which uses the string replace function to get long formulas past the 255 character limit: [link](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/01/10/entering-long-array-formulas-in-vba/)

Comment: in some cases Excel could be fooled about 255 limitation by simply putting properly formulated string as string as the value of the cell. In this case.  it seems to be working. `Dim Str as string` then `Str ="=IF(IF(AND(OR.........` and finally `Selection.value=str` may be doing the trick. However check the formula after being put into the cell.

Comment: @ArcherBird Wow thanks! I'll have to try this then it looks perfect. I'll just take a look at where I can cutoff the formula and take it from there.

Comment: @AhmedAU Thanks! I'll be sure to try this, if this works it'll be even less to deal with. Edit 1: It seems to not pick up as an array however. I'll try Archer's split string solution

Comment: @Serg - the tricky bit is that you cannot arbitrarily split your formula. You have to put the formula into the FormulaArray property in chunks that represent a valid formula; otherwise, you'll get more errors. I've created a solution for you below. Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and built a custom solution just for you. Here, you'll see I broke up your formula into smaller parts and substitute them back together (just like the good 'ol days back in algebra class).

Also note, that I don't use the `Selection` object as you do in your question. I recommend working with Ranges directly rather than using `.Select`, `Selection.` or `.Activate` and so on. So In my example below I assume the range you have "Selected" is A1 on the first worksheet.

```
strFormula = "=IF(IF(AND(OR(C2<>C1,B2<>B1),Pay_Periods!$J$2<>0),MAX(W_W),MAX(X_X))=0,""""," & _
             "IF(AND(OR(C2<>C1,B2<>B1),Pay_Periods!$J$2<>0),MAX(Y_Y),MAX(Z_Z)))"
strFormulaW_W = "IF(Pay_Periods!$C$2:$C$250>=Pay_Periods!$J$1+(14*Pay_Periods!$J$3)," & _
                "IF(Pay_Periods!$B$2:$B$250<=Pay_Periods!$J$1+(14*Pay_Periods!$J$3),Pay_Periods!$C$2:$C$250))"
strFormulaX_X = "IF((Pay_Periods!$C$2:$C$250>=Sheet1!G2)*(IF(AND(Sheet1!C2=Sheet1!C1,Sheet1!G1<Sheet1!G2+14)," & _
                "Pay_Periods!$C$2:$C$250<(G2+14),IF(AND(C2=C1,B2=B1),Pay_Periods!$C$2:$C$250<G1,1))),Pay_Periods!$C$2:$C$250,"""")"
strFormulaY_Y = "IF(Pay_Periods!$C$2:$C$250>=Pay_Periods!$J$1+(14*Pay_Periods!$J$3),IF(Pay_Periods!$B$2:$B$250<=" & _
                "Pay_Periods!$J$1+(14*Pay_Periods!$J$3),Pay_Periods!$C$2:$C$250))"
strFormulaZ_Z = "IF((Pay_Periods!$C$2:$C$250>=Sheet1!G2)*(IF(AND(Sheet1!C2=Sheet1!C1,Sheet1!B2=Sheet1!B1," & _
                "Sheet1!G1<Sheet1!G2+14),Pay_Periods!$C$2:$C$250<(G2+14),IF(AND(C2=C1,B2=B1),Pay_Periods!$C$2:$C$250<G1,1))),Pay_Periods!$C$2:$C$250,"""")"

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
    .FormulaArray = strFormula
    .Replace "W_W", strFormulaW_W
    .Replace "X_X", strFormulaX_X
    .Replace "Y_Y", strFormulaY_Y
    .Replace "Z_Z", strFormulaZ_Z
End With
```

Comment: WOW THANKS! That really helped! I was trying to work out a way to split up the formula, but you really went the extra step thank you so much!

Comment: @Serg NP! It's a very slow pre-Thanksgiving Day at work and I'm bored. Happy to help :-)

Comment: Also I agree with that definitive range rather than select is better, I just kept it as selection to show exactly how it was recorded in the macro. Usually I record the formula through a macro and change the coding up from there. Less to write in you know.